# Getting the GStreamer audio test source in a format to be listenable by the standard HTML audio player

Tags: html, audio, gstreamer

I'm doing something a bit more complicated, but the part I'm stuck on is using a udp stream to get the gstreamer audio test source to be listenable in the standard HTML5 audio player. It seems webm is the best way to do this so I created the following pipeline

`gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! vorbisenc ! vorbisparse ! webmmux streamable=true ! udpsink host=localhost port=8000`

The HTML audio player looks like this:

`<audio src="http://localhost:8000" type='audio/webm; codecs="vorbis"' controls preload="none"></audio>`

No dice on hearing it though. Any thoughts to nudge me in the right direction?

Incidentally, I can make GStreamer hear the above pipeline only with tcp, not UDP, so I think theres a fundmanetal issue with the pipeline. I've also tried rtpvorbispay with no luck.

Comment: FYI I got this to work with a TCP server, but would love to get it working with UDP. Here's the TCP solution with my system mic - can also use the audiotstsrc:  gst-launch-1.0 alsasrc buffer-time=1000000 ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! webmmux streamable=true min-cluster-duration=0 ! tcpserversink port=8080